# tf.image.crop_and_resize() returns broken cropped image

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, bounding-box

I'm trying to capture the cropped image using bounding boxes from Faster R-CNN implemented by TensorFlow API. (especially, I followed and customized [this tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) from tensorflow)

My code following the tutorial above is below:

```
for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS[0:1]:
            image = Image.open(image_path)
            image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
            image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)

            (_image_tensor,_boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
              [image_tensor,detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
              feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})

            test = tf.image.crop_and_resize(image=image_np_expanded,
                                                             boxes=[[0.27640104,0.2573258,0.57859987,0.7340185]],
                                                             box_ind=[0],
                                                             crop_size=[50,50])
            plt.figure()
            plt.imshow(image_np)

            plt.figure()
            plt.imshow(test[0].eval())
```

when the code above is executed, the result shows the picture below:
[image]

As you can see, the second one which is the cropped image is broken. The value of bounding box is the first value of the variable '_boxes' which is ***"_boxes[0]"***

Is there anything I'm missing? I'm stuck with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `tf.image.crop_and_resize` expects pixel values in the range [0,1]. Changing your code to

```
test = tf.image.crop_and_resize(image=image_np_expanded/255., ...)
```

solved the problem for me.

Comment: it solves for me too. thanks but why did you use "256."? I did use "255."

Comment: Thanks for fixing, how did you suggest that solution by just seeing the broken image?

Comment: I didn't just see it, I tried it myself and played around with it until it worked. It is actually a bit surprising because crop_and_resize is only supposed to perform linear interpolation, which in principle should not require checking for saturation. But apparently somewhere along the way there's a saturation cutoff being performed.

Comment: Thanks for your sincerity!

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow offers [tf.image.convert_image_dtype](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/convert_image_dtype) for the conversion between int and float. It is in particular useful when converting back to int (and using `saturate=True`). But I would recommend using it in either direction.